# Что делает php код

Tags: php

Случайно нашел такой код, и заинтересовался для чего его можно использовать

```
       // это первый пример

        static::ob_start();

        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

    // это второй пример
    $_viewFile_ = 'html/view.php';
    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush(false);
    require($_viewFile_);
    return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Функции контроля вывода http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Эти ф-ции используются, например, для того, чтобы отрисовать шаблон, и HTML-код поместить в переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это сохранение в кеш.

PHP функция `ob_start` перехватывает весь последующий вывод в буфер и позволяет обработать его в конце работы скрипта. Простыми словами мы получаем весь контент сайта в переменной `$content`.

Для примера фрагмент:

```
ob_start();

include($file);

$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Такую конструкцию применяют для рендеринга страниц, когда нужно в одну переменную записать динамически сгенерированную html страницу.